# Swap logical operator arguments for faster evaluation?

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, lazy-evaluation, multiple-languages

Does any programming language implement swapping of arguments of logical operation (such as AND, OR) for faster evaluation?

Example (I think such method could be implemented in a lazy evaluation language like Haskell)

1. Lets say we have defined two predicates `A` and `B`.
2. During program execution, `B` was evaluated to "True" and `A` was not evaluated
3. In the later execution we have condition `IF A OR B`
4. Arguments of "OR" are swapped, and the condition becomes `IF B OR A`
5. Condition is evaluated to "True" without evaluating `A`

Comment: I'm not aware of Haskell doing this automatically. One question: will `B` always be evaluated prior to the `if` while `A` may or may not be evaluated by this point in execution?

Comment: I am interested in both scenarios. If program flow was determined to evaluate `B` always prior to `A`, it could be optimized in compile time. If it was not, some just-in-time checks could be implemented to make use of the already evaluated argument in logical operator evaluation.

Comment: With some effort it could be done, but it wouldn't be that big of an advantage. Besides: in the end what gets executed is machine code. And CPUs already perform branch prediction pretty well, so if a certain condition can be predicted the hardware is likely to already take that into account without having to "swap arguments".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under lazy evaluation, AND and OR are not commutative.

```
foo :: Int -> Bool
foo n = False && foo (n+1)  -- evaluates to False

bar :: Int -> Bool
bar n = bar (n+1) && False  -- diverges
```

Under eager evaluation (strict semantics), and absence of side effects, they are commutative. I am not aware of any usual optimization being done by some compiler here, though. (Constants folding aside.)

If side effects are present, AND/OR are not commutative, of course. For instance, an Ocaml compiler can not swap the arguments unless it can prove that at least one of them is side effect-free.

Comment: It is a very good point, that the AND/OR operators are non commutative in a general case. Probably the feature I requested is not implemented in any language by default.

Answer (score 3):

It's not done automatically as part of the language (possibly because it would not be *free* to perform this reordering check, so you would often end up paying for an optimization that can't be made). However, there are library functions you can use to this end. See, for example, [`unamb`](http://conal.net/blog/posts/functional-concurrency-with-unambiguous-choice). With that, you can write

```
(|||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
a ||| b = (a || b) `unamb` (b || a)
```

And if one operation is cheaper to compute, it can be chosen.

Comment: In the literature this operation is called `por` for `parallel or`.

Comment: Besides the literature, this operation is also called `por` in the `unamb` package that was linked to. So no need to write it yourself in common usage -- I expect the source here is meant to be pedagogical rather than an example of how you should use the package.

Comment: I was not aware of existence of `unamb`, it's a really interesting find. I think with considerable effort such feature can be implemented in any object-oriented language using [Virtual Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for the `A` and `B`, and proxy-aware `AND`/`OR` operator which would check whether the values need to be computed.